# Plot a column chart by count of Start and End date but its not counting correctly

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to Count Start and End date so that I can plot a graph date vs count in PowerBi.

1. I created a Calendar and have an active relationship with Start date, counting start date with below Dax:

```
Start = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Data[Start Date]))
```

2. I have inactive relationship with end date to a calendar table, counting end date with below Dax:

```
End= 
CALCULATE(
    COUNTA(Data[End Date]), 
    USERELATIONSHIP('Calendar'[Date], Data[End Date]), 
    ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[End Date])
)
```

My Data:

```
ID  Start Date  End Date
1   17/05/2021  04/06/2021
2   17/05/2021  04/06/2021
3   17/05/2021  15/10/2021
4   17/05/2021  04/06/2021
5   17/05/2021  18/05/2021
6   17/05/2021  28/05/2021
7   17/05/2021  21/05/2021
8   13/05/2021  13/05/2021
9   12/05/2021  21/05/2021
10  11/05/2021  20/05/2021
11  10/05/2021  21/06/2021
12  10/05/2021  10/05/2021
13  10/05/2021  06/06/2021
14  10/05/2021  14/05/2021
15  10/05/2021  14/05/2021
16  10/05/2021  15/05/2021
17  09/05/2021  16/05/2021
18  09/05/2021  16/05/2021
19  07/05/2021  14/05/2021
20  04/05/2021  14/05/2021
21  28/04/2021  14/05/2021
22  28/04/2021  14/05/2021
23  06/04/2021  12/05/2021
24  14/03/2021  14/05/2021
25  07/12/2020  14/05/2021
26  04/11/2019  14/05/2021
```

However, above DAX syntax is not counting for certain dates - can anyone help, please? I got results for 4th, 7th, 9th, 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th and 17th May but nothing for 14th May even though there is a count for it.

[Result:Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyG1Y.png)

[Result:Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMkiN.png)

Comment: You have issue for both start and end measure? or only end? 1 in start column for all dates, is expected?

Comment: Hi, Start measure works fine only End measure fails to bring correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue belongs to your inactive relation. 14th May is not getting any count as this date is not available in column "start". Can you please try this below measure-

```
End= 

var current_row_date  = MIN('Calendar'[Date])

RETURN
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        ALL(Data),
        Data[End Date] = current_row_date
    )
)
```